# Twilio TwimlResponse not a constructor

Tags: node.js, twilio

I have followed the other answers to this and have simplified my call down to this:

```
var http = require('http');
var twilio = require('twilio');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
     resp.say({voice:'woman'}, 'ahoy hoy! Testing Twilio and node.js');
     res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type':'text/xml'
     });
     res.end(resp.toString());
}).listen(1337);
```

This returns:

```
TypeError: twilio.TwimlResponse is not a constructor
at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jmmann\Projects\node-sms\server.js:9:14)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:548:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
```

Any idea/suggestions?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using because TwimlResponse is deprecated in the current 3.X version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are trying to use the old deprecated version 2.X code with the current version 3.X SDK.
Here is some [demo code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/node/programmable-voice?code-sample=code-generate-twiml-to-say-a-message&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x) from Twilio's website to do this using the current 3.X version of the SDK:

```
const http = require('http');
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Create TwiML response
    const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

    twiml.say('Hello from your pals at Twilio! Have fun.');

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());
})
.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('TwiML server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

If you are using the old 2.X version of the SDK you can switch their example using the selector near the top right of the page.

Comment: Thank you so much for the 2.x/3.x info, that was exactly the problem. 
    `const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;`